# Minimize Lotus Notes 8.5 client to the system tray?

Tags: notification-area, lotus-notes

How can I minimize Lotus Notes 8.5 to the system tray just like Microsoft Outlook does?

I've seen some advices that say I should install some utility that does it, is that the only way? no IBM add-on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lotus Notes doesn't have support for this. But you can do it with TrayIt application.

[Tray It! website](http://www.teamcti.com/trayit/trayit.htm)

Comment: @MicTech, Thanks!  I didn't give it a try yet, but not having to install this app looks like a great feature... (I do think this is a basic feature IBM should of added to there Clint...)

Comment: Sadly, the manufacturer homepage has been down for quite a while now. Is there any other comparable client that is still under active development besides TrayIt? Alltray seems to be down, too and Eusing looks like it's from a different century..

Comment: @farosch http://alternativeto.net/software/trayit-/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is such an add-on made by IBM, but a lot of programs can do this.

One of them is [Eusing Software Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm). It can save your desired settings so it'll work each time one of the specified windows opens.

Answer (score 0):

[Alltray](http://alltray.trausch.us/) is a workaround that will allow you do do this on linux.

Answer (score 0):

**RBTray!**

I just found exactly what I was looking for- RBTray! A really simple program that even has 64bit support, works fine on Windows 10 and is not a complete waste of resources, since it's only 88KB.

Get it from [here](http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/)!